# Open CV- Variable dimensioning of Kalman Filter

Tags: c++, opencv, kalman-filter

I am working on vehicle tracking application using EKF. I want to know whether it is possible to vary the dimensionality of state, measurement vector and the transition vector in the OpenCV Implementation of Kalman Filter to track multiple objects. If yes, how should i procees? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some code that you have already written and need help fixing

Comment: Unless there are measurements between the vehicles, or terms in your state dynamics model that involve more than one vehicle, a kalman filter that tracks many vehicles will give the same results as an array of filters each tracking one vehicle.

Comment: @dmuir yespoint, i made my application with an array of filters